# change width and heigth of a cell from xlwings

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am working with an excel file from xlwings and I want to change the width and height of each cell from code, ideally to create a perfect square, is that possible?

In the documentation, I found a height attribute when using range:

```
ws1.range('A1').height
```

but it is read only, so that doesn't help.

I know there is a autofit method in xlwings that works perfectly well to set the width/height of the cell, so influencing those attributes shold be doable, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You can check out the [docs](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Range.column_width) and try out integers:

```
sheet.range("A1").column_width = 100
sheet.range("A1").row_height = 100
```